# Chartjs doesn't update x axis labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs 4.3.0 ( vanilla js ) and I have a filter that displays daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly data depending of the option selected. My chart option contains this:

```
scales: {
   x: {
     type: 'time',
     time: {
        unit: getUnit(data.filterChart)
     },
     distribution: 'series',
     min: new Date(chartData.labels[0]).setHours(0,0,0,0),
     max: new Date(chartData.labels[chartData.labels.length - 1]).setHours(0,0,0,0),
   }
}
```

The problem is when I change from monthly/quarterly to weekly/daily the data doesn't update, it stays the same data as previous filter. If for example I remove the `type` field from the options, then the chart works perfectly. But I can't remove it because I have some functionalities that don't work without that.

Note: the chart works fine when I change between monthly and quarterly, the problem is when I have more data than the previous filter